# Can a Magus use Expansive Spellstrike with a Conflux spell, and if so what exactly happens?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, magus, focus-pool

All the starting conflux spells for the various Magus hybrid studies let you make a strike. As far as I can tell, these are eligible for spellstrike if you have Expansive Spellstrike (without the feat, they're not applicable as they don't require a *spell* attack)

- Conflux spells are spells
- They require 1 action
- They seem like they would qualify as a "a harmful spell that can target a creature or that has an area of a burst, cone, or line" (in particular, Thunderous Strike has a cone, in case the "make a strike" part isn't enough to qualify)

Am I missing/misinterpreting something that precludes the use of one of these conflux spells as a spellstrike? Assuming they are a valid choice, how exactly would it play out?

- One attack roll, double damage of a strike + whatever benefit from the conflux spell?
- One attack to land the spell strike, then another to land the strike from the spell (with MAP? without MAP? presumably has to be against the spellstrike target?)
- Something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## You cannot use Spellstrike with 1st level Conflux spells

Spells that "***target** a creature or that has an **area** of a burst, cone, or line*" have either a [***Targets***](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=289) entry or an [***Area***](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=172) entry.
The 1st level Conflux spells have neither, as they all target you.

### You could use it with *Force Fang*, but you should not

It seems to be the only Conflux spell with with a Targets entry, but the main advantage of it is that you do not need to hit with it and it does not allow a save. You would lose this by using it with Spellstrike.
You are much better off just using Spellstrike with a cantrip, and use this to do some more damage while recharging Spellstrike.